# Error in web.config of sharepoint central admin in SP 2013 on-prem

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, web-config

am getting the below error after running the config wizard of my sp 2013 server farm

> Log Name:      Application
>   Source:        SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard
>   Date:          12/9/2016 3:11:21 PM
>   Event ID:      104
>   Task Category: None
>   Level:         Error
>   Keywords:      Classic
>   User:          N/A
>   Computer:      server1
>   Description:
>   Failed to provision the SharePoint Central Administration Web Application.
>   An exception of type System.Xml.XmlException was thrown.  Additional exception information: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.
>   System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.
>      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
>      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
>      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>      at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
>      at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
>      at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAspConfigurationFile.ApplyZoneSettingsToWebConfig(Uri responseUri, SPIisSettings settings)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Provision()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceInstance.Provision()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.ProvisionAdminVs()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.Run()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
>   Event Xml:
>   
>     
>       
>       104
>       2
>       0
>       0x80000000000000
>       
>       11225
>       Application
>       srvr1
>       
>     
>     
>       Failed to provision the SharePoint Central Administration Web Application.
>   An exception of type System.Xml.XmlException was thrown.  Additional exception information: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.
>   System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.
>      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
>      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
>      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>      at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
>      at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
>      at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAspConfigurationFile.ApplyZoneSettingsToWebConfig(Uri responseUri, SPIisSettings settings)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Provision()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceInstance.Provision()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.ProvisionAdminVs()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.Run()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to solve this is to create a new CA on an app server. Simply run

```
New-SPCentralAdministration -Port 2016
```

Comment: create a new CA ? never heard about this powershell script!! anyway, i will have a try  !!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a website that might give you the answer, the link is below.  This website suggests that SharePoint is on the wrong OS version.  I am currious, is this a fresh install or a long running production SharePoint server?  If is is a new SP server, consider starting over by formatting the drive.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f35f7bb1-abdc-46f4-8fb4-0bd3870d8b5c/failed-to-provision-the-sharepoint-central-administration-web-application-systemxmlxmlexception?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: no, my OS is win server 2012 R2 and i already installed sp 2013 sp1 on this server recently. the oly thing i tried to do  is that, FBA configuration for my claims web appln against the LDAP provider - AD . i got the details from my company's infra team about the AD and DC, OU  names and i have filled the entries in the central admin web config as part of my FBA config. After that i saw, the fba didnt work and i removed those entries and revert the original web config of CA. Now suddenly am seeing that these errors were propped up. and i already ran the config wizard twice still in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Never EVER update the CA web Config manually this always happens, just re run your product config and everything will be fine!

Comment: that didn't work i tried with twice. ran the config wizard twice and then i got these errors from my eventvwr log files.